# is there a way to test the project tango unity project samples in editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

is there a way to test the project tango unity project samples (without deactivating tango manager) in editor (avoiding having to build to device each time)?

- maybe with a sample camera dump input source?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can only emulate the motion tracking data on the editor. To do that, you will need to use the [DeltaPoseController](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Tango%20Delta%20Camera.prefab) prefab in the Tango prefabs.

Pointcloud, color camera or ADF feature are not available through the editor mode. To test these features, you have to push it to the device.